# incompatible types when returning type 'float *' but 'float' was expected

Tags: c, pointers

i keep getting this error:
incompatible types when returning type 'float *' but 'float' was expected
`return unit;`
when i compile my c program, and i dont know how to solve it, can you help me, thanks

```
int i[3] = {1, 0, 0};
int j[3] = {0, 1, 0};
int k[3] = {0, 0, 1};
void addvector(int x, int y, int z) {
  pointlist[n_vett][0] = x;
  pointlist[n_vett][1] = y;
  pointlist[n_vett][2] = z;
  pointlist[n_vett][3] = 1;
  n_vett++;
}
float getlenght(int riga) {
  float lenght = sqrt(
      pow(pointlist[riga][0], 2)
    + pow(pointlist[riga][1], 2)
    + pow(pointlist[riga][2], 2) );
  return lenght;
}
float unitvector(int riga) {
  float unit[4] = {(pointlist[riga][0] / getlenght(riga)),
           (pointlist[riga][1] / getlenght(riga)),
           (pointlist[riga][2] / getlenght(riga)), 1};
  return unit;
}
float molForScalar(int riga, int n) {
  float product[4] = {
      (pointlist[riga][0] * n),
      (pointlist[riga][1] * n),
      (pointlist[riga][2] * n),
      1
  };
  return product;
}
int scalarproduct(int riga1, int riga2) {
  int result =
      (pointlist[riga1][0] * pointlist[riga2][0])
    + (pointlist[riga1][1] * pointlist[riga2][1])
    + (pointlist[riga1][2] * pointlist[riga2][2]);
  return result;
}
float getcos(int riga1, int riga2) {
  float cos =
      (scalarproduct(riga1, riga2) / (getlenght(riga1) * getlenght(riga2)));
  return cos;
}
```

Comment: **You're returning** the conversion of a local array to **a pointer** to its first element. Remember the array ceases to exist when the function terminates and any use the caller makes of that pointer is illegal.

Comment: Step 1 is to format code so it is readable. Also, the posted code does not call `float unitvector(int riga)` so its usage is unknown. There is no context for `return unit;` however if you want to return the local array (pointer) it would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Step 2 is to make sure your code has the definitions of **all** variables it uses (like `pointlist` and `n_vett`.

Comment: it's a work in progress code, but it need to normalize a vector, its test called in function main

Comment: Not the main problem (which is addressed in the accepted answer), but `scalarproduct` returns an `int`, you've declared `result` as an `int`, but you're casting it to `float` on return?  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two functions are the problem (the same):

```
float unitvector(int riga) {
  float unit[4] = {(pointlist[riga][0] / getlenght(riga)),
           (pointlist[riga][1] / getlenght(riga)),
           (pointlist[riga][2] / getlenght(riga)), 1};
  return unit;
}
float molForScalar(int riga, int n) {
  float product[4] = {
      (pointlist[riga][0] * n),
      (pointlist[riga][1] * n),
      (pointlist[riga][2] * n),
      1
  };
  return product;
}
```

Return type is `float` but you tried to return an array of floats. There is several ways to correct this, but you should know that there is no simple way to return an array in C. Here is a simple solution:

```
void unitvector(int riga,float unit[4]) {
  unit[0] = (pointlist[riga][0] / getlenght(riga));
  unit[1] = (pointlist[riga][1] / getlenght(riga));
  unit[2] = (pointlist[riga][2] / getlenght(riga));
  unit[3] = 1;
}
```

and then use it passing the *vector* as the second argument.

The idea is to transmit the *vector* in such a way the function is able to modify it.